# Return 444 Instead of 400

Tags: nginx, http

If someone makes an http request to an https resource on my nginx server, they get an error 400. "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port" Is there a way to return 444 instead?

When I search for this error, I can only find people that have had configuration issues they were trying to fix. But in my case, my configuration is fine - I'm trying to minimize impact of illegitimate requests.

Edit: I'm using this to prevent direct IP access to my server. If someone makes an http request, they get response 400 instead of 444. I just want no response.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/n.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/n2.pem;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```

Comment: This probably needs to be tackled at the application level.

Comment: It would be better not to answer at all.  Sending http to the https port takes effort, it can hardly be a mistake.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out how to do. How do I just not answer at all, instead of returning error 400?

Comment: nginx handles that scenario internally. It is not something you can (or should) control.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have nginx respond with 444 this way:

```
error_page 497 =444 /444.html;

location = /444.html {
        return 444;
}
```

Comment: Where does the 497 error come from?

Comment: 497 is the error code for HTTP Request Sent to HTTPS Port (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: Interesting. I've never actually seen nginx send that code (and it sends 400 on my production boxes). When was this added and/or how do you enable it?

Comment: It's not officially documented, so very little info is available

Comment: Have you actually tried it to see if it works?

Comment: Of course, that's why i've posted it here. If you use a non-standard port for https you'll get baidu spiders and others hitting it eventually. They get 444 with this solution

Comment: OK, so how do you actually get it to work?

Comment: Just copy/paste these lines inside your server block and restart nginx

Comment: On what version of nginx?

Comment: I'm using nginx/1.15.8

Comment: That's even stranger, because I just tried it on 1.20.0 and it returns 400, not 497. Maybe this has been removed from the code.